# How to check when a user last updated password

Tags: users

I would like to display a message to any user who has not changed their password since yesterday (4/21/14).

Does Drupal keep track of when the password was last updated? If so, how can I access that information?

Comment: Have you lookup http://drupal.org/project/password_expire ?

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/password_expire appears to be a Drupal 6 module. https://drupal.org/project/force_password_change is the Drupal 7 equivalent. However, I don't think either of them allow you to check how long since an existing password has been updated.

Answer (score 4):

Drupal out of the box does not keep track of password changes.  However, there are modules that do:

Drupal 7: The module [**Force Password Change**](https://drupal.org/project/force_password_change) keeps track of it. The data is in its schema (`$schema['force_password_change_users']`), in the field `last_password_change` (shown below):

```
'last_password_change' => array (
  'description' => t('A UNIX timestamp referring to the date that the user last changed their password'),
  'type' => 'int',
  'unsigned' => TRUE,
  'length' => 10,
  'default' => NULL,
),
```

Drupal 6: The module [**Password Expire**](https://drupal.org/project/password_expire) keeps track of it. The data is in its schema (`$schema['password_expire']`), in the field `timestamp` (shown below):

```
'timestamp' => array(
  'type' => 'int',
   'not null' => 1,
   'unsigned' => TRUE,
   'default' => 0,
   'disp-width' => '11',
   'description' => 'Date user last updated password',
 ),
```

You could install one of these modules (depending upon what Drupal version you're using), and just query its table to extract this information as a UNIX timestamp from the field.

It would also be quite trivial to add this by means of a custom module:

You should be able to use [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) (where `FORM_ID` is `password_change`) to intercept any password changes and record the timestamp for the event along with the `uid` in a table in the database.

Comment: So, it sounds like I can create code or use a module to track when a user changes their password in the future. BUT, that I can't tell when a user last updated their password prior to installing the code/module.

Comment: @stpaultim, correct.